# Show listings from Impress Listing plugin in random order using taxonomy and terms

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy, terms, order

I am not able to get the listings to show up. I have verified the slug for the post type and the taxonomy. This code I know works because I have used it for other post types and taxonomy's. Any insight as to why this would not be working here would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php

$tag = 'commercial_for_lease';

// Set up custom query with meta_query
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'wp-listings', // your property post type slug
    'posts_per_page'         => 50,
    'orderby'                => 'rand', // order by
    'order'                  => 'ASC', // Show earlier events first
    'tax_query'              => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy'  => 'property-types',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms'     => array($tag)
                                ))
                            );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-md-4" id="<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>">
            <div class="row">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="item-container">                                                    
                    <div class="item-container-img">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="item-container-text">
                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?><h4>
                        <h5><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'listing-price', true); ?></h5>                                                                   
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
   </div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); 
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest starting your query by first only passing the post_type and posts_per_page arguments. This will let you know if you're getting the right entries and if so then begin to use your filters (orderby, order, etc).

Comment: Thanks BShelling! After digging into the plugin more I found I was using the incorrect post_type slug. Thanks